# What's that pipe at the exhaust of this engines?

Tags: jet-engine

On my last vacation, I took lots of photos from landing aircraft, and here are two showing the engine of two B737:

[image][image]

**What is that pipe on the cone of the exhaust for?**

I also saw them on other, larger aircraft. 
Often, the exhaust looks like a large, black hole where you don't see anything inside. Maybe, those engines have such pipes, too, but you can't see them.

My guess is it's for cooling of the shaft or similar, as the exhaust gases should create a vacuum in the pipe.

Comment: Exact duplicate of a question asked yesterday.

Comment: Its there basically to vent air out of the oil pump

Comment: Quite interesting. I have this question in mind since some time, but didn't notice it was asked yesterday...

Comment: Never seen it happen before. Whats also weird is the 2 pictures that have different shaped exhaust nozzles, but its a slight difference.